# How to deploy assembly jar and use it as provided dependency?

Tags: maven, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

Using spark over hbase and hadoop using Yarn, 
an assembly library among other libraries is provided server side.
(called like spark-looongVersion-haddop-looongVersion.jar)
it includes numerous libraries.

When the spark jar is sent as a job to the server for execution, conflicts may arise between the libraries included in the job and the server libraries (assembly jar and possibly other libraries) .

I need to include this assembly jar as a "provided" maven dependency to avoid conflicts between client dependencies and server classpath
how can I deploy and use this assembly jar as a provided dependency ?

Answer (score 0):

> how can I deploy and use this assembly jar as a provided dependency ?

An assembly jar is a regular jar file and so as any other jar file can be a library dependency if it's available in the artifact repo to download it from, e.g. Nexus, Artifactory or similar.

The quickest way to do it is to "install" it in your Maven local repository (see Maven's [Guide to installing 3rd party JARs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)). That however binds you to what you have locally available and so will quickly get out of sync with what other teams are using.

The recommended way is to deploy the dependency using [Apache Maven Deploy Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/).

Once it's deployed, declaring it as a dependency is not different from declaring other dependencies.

Comment: Ok, so if after deployment I include the assembly jar as a provided dependency, will all libraries inside (listed by artefact and version in files under WEB-INF ) be excluded like if I had individualy included each as provided dependencies ?

Comment: Isn't the assembly jar used on the server and provided from hadoop installation by the server ? Thus shouldn't all teams use the same ?

Answer (score 0):

**Provided dependencies scope**

Spark dependencies must be excluded from the assembled JAR. If not, you should expect weird errors from Java classloader during application startup. Additional benefit of assembly without Spark dependencies is faster deployment. Please remember that application assembly must be copied over the network to the location accessible by all cluster nodes (e.g: HDFS or S3).

Comment: You seems to have some knowledge about the problem, thanks.